# Custom field query multiple post types - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I m trying to query two custom post types for data and the below isn't working. I tried a few versions ... but no luck.

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => array('custom1', 'custom2'),
      'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      //the first two keys are custom fields found in custom1 custom posts
      array(
        'key' => 'firstKey',
        'value' => 3
      ),
      array(
        'key' => 'secondKey',
        'value' => cool
      ),
      //the third key can be found in custom2 custom posts
      array(
        'key' => 'thirdKey',
        'value' => 3
      )
      )
  );
```

Comment: What posts are you trying to get, and what's not working?

Comment: Trying to get custom fields from the post where `thirdKey` = `3`. Now the custom fields are blank.

Comment: Your AND relation means that only posts that have ALL of the keys specified will be returned. From your comments, it sounds like that will never happen.

Comment: so how should I format this? another query?

Comment: Yes, a different query, but your answer to the first comment is a little confusing. If you are just looking for a post with thirdkey = 3 and thirdkey can only be in post type custom2, why don't you just use a simple query with those values?

Comment: it s a bit more complicated. let s say there are cool and uncool users. the 3 represents the month a user clicks on. so if a cool user clicks on March, he will only get posts from custom that have cf values cool and 3. now the last custom field contains specific data for March (3)

Comment: Then it sounds like you want to create the meta_query array dynamically, depending on whether the user is cool or not, then just use 'meta_query' => $meta_query.

Comment: would you mind sharing an example?

Comment: See answer. Maybe not as complex as your exact situation, but maybe will make the idea clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments: If you want to use custom queries for different types of users, then you probably want to create your query dynamically.

For example, if users of type 'cool' get special treatment, then the basic idea would be:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'custom' );
if (user is 'cool') {
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
         'relation' => 'AND',
         array(
             'key' => 'secondKey',
             'value' => 'cool'
         ),
         array(
             'key' => 'thirdKey',
             'value' => 3
         )
    };
} else {
    $args['meta-key'] = 'thirdKey';
    $args['meta_value'] = 3
}
```

This just pass this as WP_Query($args) like you would if it had been static.